# I want to write a class whose instances are functions

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

In typescript, how would I successfully go about creating a class whose instances are functions? Specifically, I want all the functions in the class to return an HTMLelement.

I want to be able to have functions in that class that look like:

```js
function givDiv() {
  const div = document.createElement('div')
  div.id = 'givenDiv'
  // other things I might want to do to div
  return div
}
```

Comment: The *instances* are functions? Could you show a [mre] of how that would look?  (e.g., if the class is named `Foo`, would you be writing `const c = new Foo()` and then `c(123)` or something?)

Comment: I wish I could show you a minimal reproducible example of what I'm looking for, but if I could then I wouldn't be asking the question. Your e.g. looks like the kind of thing I'm looking for. I just have no idea how to create the class constructor.

Comment: Back up and explain why having a class whose instances are functions makes sense: what are you trying to do that made you go "you know what, this calls for a class that yields functions when instantiated". Because that's almost certainly the wrong idea for whatever it is you're trying to actually do.

Comment: Comment is opinion based. There is not anything morally right or wrong about instantiating functions. It is what I believe to be most expedient for my use-case.

Comment: could you give an example of the expected API? i.e. if you had what you are asking for, could you provide a code snipper of how you would use it?

Comment: • A [mre] doesn't mean "answer your own question", in this case it means "show us how you need this thing to work with examples of use". • Callable class instances are technically possible, but they are unconventional, tricky to accomplish, have weird side effects, and TS doesn't model them well, so you'd have to write some ugly code like shown [here in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/w84oAw). You will undoubtedly have a smoother experience if you just use methods. • Since you already accepted an answer that does not actually address the question you asked, how should we proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You can use the class constructor to return the element that you want. E.g.:

```js
class MyDiv {
    constructor() {
        return document.createElement('div');
    }
}
```

Usage:

```js
const div = new MyDiv();

/* returns a <div></div> */
```

I dont know your scenery, but this can be very counterintuitive. You may consider using static methods. E.g.:

```js
class CreateElement {
  static create(el, props) {
    return Object.assign(document.createElement(el), props);
  }
  
  static div(props = {}) {
    return CreateElement.create('div', props);
  }

  static p(props = {}) {
    return CreateElement.create('p', props);
  }
}
```

On this class we have the generic method "create" which creates any element with the properties we assigned in "props". We use this method to create specialized methods that creates our elements for us like this:

```js
const div = CreateElement.div();
/* creates a <div></div> */

const p = CreateElement.p({ classList: 'nice' });
/* creates a <p class="nice"></p> */
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, I want a class that instantiates functions that return HTML elements. However, I appreciate the effort and what you did is somewhat helpful for my use case. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you mean you want to create a class whose *methods return HTML elements* (methods are already functions):

```
class MyClass {
    givDiv() {
        const div = document.createElement('div')
        div.id = 'givenDiv'
        // other things I might want to do to div
        return div
    }
}

const myInstance = new MyClass()
// `myInstance` is an instance of `MyClass`
const div = myInstance.givDiv()
// call the `givDiv` method on the instance, returning an HTMLDivElement
```

Comment: No, I do not mean a class with methods. I mean a class whose instances are functions, which seems possible because functions are also objects.